# HTACCESS: How to URL rewrite a sub-subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the subdomain `apps.domain.com` pointing to `domain.com/apps`

I would like to URL rewrite `appName.apps.domain.com`, where `appName` is the variable pointing to `domain.com/apps/appName`

- **I'm looking for an internal forward (no change in the browser's URL)**

What should I have in my `.htaccess` file and where should I save it? Within `/apps/` folder? Or within the `root` folder?

Lastly, if it is not possible with an `.htaccess` file, how can I do this? I'm using a Linux godaddy server as host.

---

**** **Question updated 07/08/2018; added more details** ****

- **I am using GoDaddy SHARED hosting**
- It is currently hosting multiple domains
- Thus, the directory structure is `public_html/domain.com/`, where `/domain.com/` is the name of the hosted domain name(s)
- The sub-subdomain is exclusive to 1 specific domain

**Example:**

- If the domain name is `domain.com`
- There's multiple names, but to give an example. if the name of the app is `awesome`
- If the uri is: `awesome.apps.domain.com` will point to...`public_html/domain.com/apps/awesome/`
- If the uri is: `ubertz.apps.domain.com` will point to...`public_html/domain.com/apps/ubertz/`
- And so on...

Comment: Please post the existing .htaccess, assuming that is what routes `apps.domain.com` to `domain.com/apps`. mod_rewrite is highly order-dependent, so we need the full context.

Comment: I used godaddy's cpanel to add a subdomain. It doesn't use an htaccess file. Right now I have no htaccess files anywhere.

Comment: @Omar Does one of their solutions work?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this code for subdomain forwarding:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.apps\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /apps/%1/$1
```

Explanation:

- In `RewriteCond` you catch app name using regular expression `(.*)` - it will be saved to variable `%1`
- In `RewriteRule` you forward everything - that's another `(.*)` expression which content will be saved in variable `$1` - to the directory `/apps/<appName>/<path after URL>`

For more information about Regular Expressions I recommend to check this tutorial: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php

You should save your `.htaccess` in the `root` directory of the domain, in your case in the `public_html/domain.com/`. If it doesn't work, place it in the `apps` folder.

Comment: I updated the question, since I noticed it was pointing to `public_html/`. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Omar Then save it in the `public_html/domain.com/`. I also updated my answer and added more information about forwarding.

Answer (score 4):

#### Create wildcard sub-subdomain

The first thing that you need to do is to create a wildcard **.apps.domain.com* sub-subdomain.

1. *(If you're using Nameservers, skip this step!)* Log in to your domain name registrar, and create an **A record** for **.apps.domain.com* *(yeah, that's an asterisk)* and point it to the server IP address. Note that DNS can take up to 48 hours to propagate.
2. Log in your web hosting account and go to the menu *'Subdomains'* under **Domains** section. Create a **Subdomain** **.apps.domain.com* that's pointed to the *"/public_html/domain.com/apps"* folder as its **Document Root**. And wait until the propagation is over.

Visit [How to create wildcard subdomain in cPanel](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-to-create-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel) and [How to Create a Sub-Subdomain](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-sub-subdomain/) for more info. If your server's configuration didn't allow you to create a wildcard sub-subdomain then just create **.domain.com* and point it to *"/public_html/domain.com/apps"*.

#### Rewrite wildcard sub-subdomain

Place these directives in the *.htaccess* file of the document root of the wildcard **.apps.domain.com* which in this case is *"/public_html/domain.com/apps"*.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.apps\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/apps/%1/$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

The `%1` is the numbered backreference of `(.+)` and the `$1` is of `(.*)`. You need to include the `[P]` flag if you URL rewrite from a specific domain ***http://**domain.com/apps/%1/$1* in the same server, without that it will be redirected. Use the `[QSA]` flag if you'll going to use the query string of a rewritten wildcard subdomain. Visit [P|proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) and [QSA|qsappend](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) for more info about them. And just tweak some adjustment if I forgot something, other than that, is the server's fault.

#### Few things to consider

You must configure your *.htaccess* file for the duplicate subdomains that will be going to exist, such the *otherwildcard.apps.domain.com*, *another.wilcard.apps.domain.com* and the *other.deep.level.apps.domain.com* that will duplicate *apps.domain.com* as they're all have the same document root. Configure to redirect or to tell to the client that those subdomains aren't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try these *.htaccess* directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.apps\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /apps/appName/$1 [P,L]
```

The RewriteRule will not redirect the user because of the [P] flag. This will redirect the request to the `mod_proxy` module which handles the request and returns the result.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html for more information.

Comment: I updated the question, since I noticed it was pointing to `public_html/`. Sorry about that.

Comment: If apps.domain.com is aleady pointing to public_html/domain.com/apps/ the htaccess should work if you place it in your apps folder. It will call "domain.com/apps/myApp" as url which should be resolved to public_html/domain.com/apps/myApp