# How to rewrite subdomain and subsubdomain into a parameter?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Can anyone please help with the following rewrite for `apache`?

Imagine I have the domain `domain.com`

What I want:

> If people request www.domain.com then return www.domain.com (ie
>   index.php in my root directory)
>
> If people request subA.subB.domain.com then return
>   www.domain.com?sub=subA.subB
>
> If people request sub.domain.com then return www.domain.com?sub=sub
>
> If people request domain.com then return www.domain.com

I know the rule here is to work on it yourself. I have. For example, the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186078/htaccess-how-to-url-rewrite-a-sub-subdomain) asks to redirect to /subA/subB - but even if I understood that answer I would not know how to adapt it to what I need, which is ?sub=subA.subB . I have tried to understand rewrite many times over the years. Ok, /sobstory -off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rewrite your subdomains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^sub=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/?)$ $1?sub=%1
```

Replace the domain as appropriate. Make sure each `.` has a slash before it as it does now.

It will only work for the index page. If you want it to work when there is something after `domain.com/` let me know.

As for making `http://domain.com` work, I suggest redirecting that to `www.domain.com` so you don't get duplicate content issues from search engines. Do that with this (add it below the above):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

No need for the slashes before the dots on that one.

Let me know if any of that is no good for you.

---

Original poster's postscript based on comments:

The above solution is correct for the question but assumes the following configurations on the server:

- The subdomain *.domain.com has been added and points to the document root for the site
- An 'A record' for *.domain.com has been configured in the DNS configuration and points to the IP address of the server

Comment: Thanks. I added directoryIndex index.php to the bottom. Currently if I enter domain.com in the address bar, my homepage is returned and the address bar updates to www.domain.com. However if I enter subA.subB.domain.com I get "Firefox can't find the server at subA.subB.domain.com." Likewise for only subA.domain.com. ?

Comment: There are two things you need to do to make that part work. First of all set your hosting up to serve either *.domain.com or the specific subdomains you need, and then, if it's not handled by your hosting, set up the DNS entries.

Comment: Sorry - that's above my understanding of configuring the server. My site is hosted on Hostgator, so I access functions via CPanel. I'm expecting to add new subdomains dynamically - that is, I will simply have data residing in the website. When someone asks for sub1.sub2 the site will check whether there is matching data, and if so, serve it. I plan on adding data continuously - hence cannot know all subdomains in advance. I will search cpanel for setting up *.domain.com but if you can fast track me on both steps that would be appreciated. Conscious this is now venturing to a new question...

Comment: I found a CP for subdomains and added *.domain.com, pointing it to my document root. Re-tested and still not working. I then found some a CP for basic configuration of DNS. It gave me the options to set A and CNAME records. I've never understood these. Wikipedia became my friend. I reasoned that a CNAME record was required from *.domain.com to domain.com based on similar for ftp but the system told me *.domain.com is reserved. I therefore tried an A record to the same IP shown for the ftp A record and others. My site now loads its page at subA.subB.domain.com - will have to test in code...

Comment: A new question might be needed. But yeah it's an A record for *.domain.com that you need and then the server needs to be willing to serve the site on that, which it sounds like it is. So seems good to go. Let me know any problems.

Comment: ... whether the subdomain parts have been passed in as parameters. Well actually, site is already coded for that test, and it works, so thank you very much.
Incidentally, subA.subB.domain.com still reports server not found, but subC.subD or any other combo works - so I gather a browser caching issue. Many thanks - stackoverflow should allow donations from question askers to answerers because you've effectively solved a coding problem for me.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it's working for you. Just voting my answer up and accepting it is enough :) Helps improve my skills working on different problems.