# Cannot redirect to sub-subdomain from subdomain using httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm attempting to setup a local development server where I can simply access any project within a directory `E:\development\projects\` and have apache automatically redirect me to the correct subdomain.

However when attempting to redirect to a sub-subdomain (`backend.project01.dev01`), I simply get a "server unreachable" message.

See my httpd-vhosts.conf for more info:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev01
    ServerAlias www.dev01
    DocumentRoot "E:\development\projects"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev01
    ServerAlias *.dev01
    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\development\projects\%1"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects\%1">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev01
    ServerAlias *.*.dev01
    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\development\projects\%2"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects\%2">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In a nutshell:

This work: 
`project01.dev01/`

This doesn't work: 
`backend.project01.dev01/`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186078/htaccess-how-to-url-rewrite-a-sub-subdomain) may help , also [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirecting-from-subdirectory-to-subdomain-using-htaccess/) ----

Comment: @SUB-HDR I know it's easier using the `RewriteEngine`, however I want a generic, all-round solution that doesn't involve me having to create new/custom `.htaccess` files every time I start a new project. The answers you provided don't help me at a global level, but at a local level.

Comment: then you could read more here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html also look at this : [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/670753/two-https-virtualhosts-on-same-server-same-port-different-subdomains) or [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) -----

Comment: @SUB-HDR I've found an example which is easier to implement, your links inspired me to take an easier approach. See my answer.

Comment: nice . good job :)

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a solution. To match sub-subdomains, you have to match the `deepest` level first.

I.e.: match `deepest.sub.domain` before `sub.domain`

The answer in this example is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev01
    DocumentRoot "E:\development\projects"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

## moved this up
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev01
    ServerAlias *.*.dev01
    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\development\projects\%2"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects\%2">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

## moved this down
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName dev01
    ServerAlias *.dev01
    VirtualDocumentRoot "E:\development\projects\%1"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "E:\development\projects\%1">
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In this example apache will always **first** attempt to match the `*.*.dev01` and if it fails, attempt to match `*.dev01`.

Hopefully this will help others in the future.